# What may be the reason for this constructor failing to initialize with the given values?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to solve an example question from a book and I encountered this problem while initializing the constructor with the values given below. Normally constructor initializes the variables beforehand. When I run the function from a function like Rational_Caller, the member function file given below gives an error as "DIVISION BY ZERO ERROR". Since I initialize the first object with given values in Rational_Caller function, I couldn't figure out why denominator gets the value 0.

this is the header file

```
// Rational Class header file

#ifndef _RATIONAL_H_
#define _RATIONAL_H_

class Rational
{
public:
    Rational(int = 0, int = 1); // default constructor
    Rational addition(const Rational&); 
    Rational subtraction(const Rational&); 
    Rational multiplication(const Rational&); 
    Rational division(const Rational&); 
    void printRational(); 
    void printRationalAsdouble(); 

private:
    int numerator; 
    int denominator; 
    void reduction(); // function to reduce using great common divisor 

}; 




#endif // !_RATIONAL_H_
```

this is the member function definitions for the file Rational.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h" // include definiton of class Rational 

using namespace std; 

Rational::Rational(int n, int d)
{
    numerator = n; 
    denominator = d; 
    reduction(); 
} 


Rational Rational::addition(const Rational& a)
{
    Rational t; 
    
    t.numerator = a.numerator * denominator; 
    t.numerator += a.denominator * numerator; 
    t.denominator = a.denominator * denominator; 
    t.reduction();
    return t; 

} 

Rational Rational::subtraction(const Rational& s)
{
    Rational t;
    t.numerator = s.numerator * denominator; 
    t.numerator -= denominator * s.numerator; 
    t.denominator = s.denominator * denominator; 
    return t; 

}  

Rational Rational::multiplication(const Rational& m)
{
    Rational t; 
    t.numerator = m.numerator * numerator; 
    t.denominator = m.denominator * denominator; 
    t.reduction(); 
    return t;   
} 

Rational Rational::division(const Rational& v)
{
    Rational t; 
    t.numerator = numerator * v.denominator; 
    t.denominator = denominator * v.numerator; 
    t.reduction(); 
    return t; 

} 


void Rational::printRational()
{
    if (denominator == 0) 
        cout << "\nDIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR!!!" << "\n";
    else if (numerator == 0) 
        cout << 0;
    else
        cout << numerator << '/' << denominator; 
} 


void Rational::printRationalAsdouble()
{
    cout << static_cast<double>(numerator) / denominator; 
} 

void Rational::reduction()
{
    int largest; 

    largest = numerator > denominator ? numerator : denominator; 

    int gcd = 0; 

    for (int loop = 2; loop <= largest; loop++)
    {
        if (numerator % loop == 0 && denominator % loop == 0)
            gcd = loop; 

        if (gcd != 0)
        {
            numerator /= gcd; 
            denominator /= gcd; 
        } 

    }

}
```

this is the file I call the functions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

#include "Rational.h" 

int main()
{
    Rational obj1(8, 14), obj2(5, 7), resobj; 

    obj1.printRational(); 
    cout << " + ";
    obj2.printRational(); 
    resobj = obj1.addition(obj2); 

    cout << " = "; 
    resobj.printRational(); 
    


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to trace reduction in a debugger?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to reduce the code you have to the parts that are relevant to reproduce the error. So in your case the error already appears at `obj1.printRational();`  so everything below is not relevant in `main`. So given that only the `reduction` and `printRational` might be relevant. `printRational` only reads  `denominator`. So the problem is likely to be in  `reduction`. So the next thing you should do is to use the debugger and check at what point `denominator` becomes `0` in that function.

Comment: Good to know [std::gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).

Comment: I can see my mistake clearly now, the greatest common divisor stays the same and divides until denom becomes zero obviously, thanks for your help !

Comment: `_RATIONAL_H_` is a reserved identifier (because it begins with an underscore).  Better to use a non-reserved identifier like `RATIONAL_H` or `RATIONAL_H_GUARD` for the header guard.  Reserved identifiers include:  double underscore anywhere in the identifier, begins with an underscore and uppercase letter, begins with an underscore and lowercase letter *in the global namespace*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proble is in `void Rational::reduction()` function.

What happens when `if (numerator % loop == 0 && denominator % loop == 0)` is false?

You should have initlise `gcd` to 0 for each iteration of for-loop or even batter, do't use `gcd` variable at all. [See it here in action](https://ideone.com/N4woUs):

```
for (int loop = 2; loop <= largest; loop++)
{
    if (numerator % loop == 0 && denominator % loop == 0)
    {
        numerator /= loop; 
        denominator /= loop; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, I see the reason now.